# How to download images and webms from 4chan?

Tags: downloads

I used to use a program for download media from 4chan but I forget about it.

Is there a way to download images and webms from 4chan?

Comment: `Right click --> Save as` doesn't work?

Comment: I know. I'm not as stupid as your brain's think. :) I'm asking about automation.

Comment: Automation in what way?

Comment: To download all webms and images.

Comment: All of the existing images and GIFs on the site at once?

Comment: No, just for a thread or board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

1. Download [this beautiful script](https://github.com/Exceen/4chan-downloader) from github.
2. Extract it to your desktop (or another folder)
3. Open the terminal in this location
4. Use this command with your thread link (example):

   `python download.py http://boards.4chan.org/g/thread/53587062`
5. It's okay. That will start a download process.